# Sybase Anyware. SQL query to determine DB version

Tags: sybase, sybase-asa

What query or command to determine Sybase SQL Anyware version?

I use **sqlsh** + **freetds** as interactive client (in Emacs).

Comment: If you are using SQL Anywhere, you should probably use the [sqlanywhere] tag, and not the [sybase-asa] tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For databases, you can use the [SYSHISTORY system view](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/syshistory-system-view.html) to find out what version the database was created at.

```
select version from SYSHISTORY where object_id = OBJ_ID_OF_DB
```

If you databases were migrated from earlier installations, and don't show the version number you expect, you probably could just create a small database, and take a look at the version history information.

Comment: I issue `select version from SYSHISTORY;` as don't  know *OBJ_ID_OF_DB*. Great! +1

Comment: could not execute statement
column 'OBJ_ID_OF_DB' not found
sqlcode=143, odbc3 state=4252

Comment: t could not execute statement

select version from SYSHISTORY where object_id = OBJ_ID_OF_DB

column 'OBJ_ID_OF_DB' not found
sqlcode=143, odbc3 state=4252
for the statement
Actually all object_ID values for my database are 0(zero) for syshistory rows

However the next statement works 
select version,* from SYSHISTORY where operation  in ('INIT', 'UPGRADE')